# C++ pause function not seeming to work within do-while loop

Tags: c++, function, while-loop, do-while

I am writing hangman in c++ that also accepts commands from the user (so that they can see clues and quit the game).

I am currently implementing the commands, but can't seem to get it to work. I am stuck on a help command that uses a `pause()` function to let the user read the text.

The pause function does not seem to be working, even though it has worked earlier in the program.

### Code So Far

Here is the code: [HelloWorld.cpp](https://compilr.com/theonlygusti/codename-zerg/HelloWorld.cpp)

```
void pause( string msg = "Press enter to continue..." ){
    cout << msg;
    cin.ignore();
}

// game loop.
do {
    correctLetters = 0;

    nl();
    showLives(lives);
    nl(5);
    showWordGuessed(wordGuessed);
    nl(1);
    cout << "Guess a letter (type /help to see commands): ";
    cin >> guess;

    if (guess.size() == 1){
        for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++){
            if (word[i] == guess) wordGuessed[i] =  word[i];
        }
    } else if (guess[0] == '/'){
        if (guess == "/ans"){

        } else if (guess == "/clue"){

        } else if (guess == "/help"){
            nl();
            cout << "Typing /ans will show you the answer and quit the game.\n";
            cout << "Typing /clue will show you one unknown letter.\n";
            cout << "Typing /guess will allow you to guess the entire word.\n";
            cout << "Typing /hangman will quit the game.\n";
            cout << "Typing /help will show you this help message.\n\n";
            pause("Press enter to continue playing...");
        } else if (guess == "/guess"){

        } else if (guess == "/hangman"){
            return 0;
        } else {

        }
    } else {
        nl();

    }

    for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++){
        if (wordGuessed[i] ==  word[i]) correctLetters++;
    }

    win = ((correctLetters == 5) ? win = true : win = false);

} while (!win);

cout << "you win";
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to have a title (subject) that is more meaningful. "Why doesn't my C++ program work?" has absolutely no information, and it will certainly not be useful to a future reader who finds it in a search result. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pause function does not quite do what you think it does.

Lets imagine reading some data from the input stream, like this:

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
```

The user types in a number, and hits return. `operator>>` will pull characters out of `cin` until it finds one that cannot be converted to an `int`, which it will leave there. In the case of normal user input, the character that is left on the stream is the newline (`\n`).

When you come to call your `pause` function, you try to do this:

```
std::cin.ignore()
```

which will ignore one single character on the input stream. Only there's a stray `\n` on the stream from the last time someone entered some data! So `pause` returns immediately.

You need to take steps to clean your input stream after use, perhaps by doing this each time after you've used `std::cin >> whatever`.

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This will drop everything after the last valid input character to the final newline. Your pause function will likely work a little better after that.

Alternatively, instead of using `>>`, you could use `getline`, which is designed to deal with newline-terminated text strings.

```
std::string stuff;
std::getline(std::cin, stuff);

if (stuff.length() > 1)
    std::cout << "Easy, tiger.\n";
```

`getline` removes the trailing `\n` for you, which will also help your `pause` function work better.

Comment: Which 'this'? I mentioned several things! But I'd recommend using the `getline` code in all the places you currently use `cin >>`. That should be an easy change, and you can see if it solves your problem.